# App that uses Task Scheduler quickly runs out of memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

The app parses files within some directory, while new files are being added to the directory. I uses ConcurrentQueue and tried to split work to the number of cores. So if there are files to process - it should process up to 4(cores) files concurrently. 
Yet the app runs OOM within seconds, after processing 10-30 files. I see the memory consumption grow to ~1.5GB quickly, than OOM error appears. 
I'm to task scheduler, so I'm probably doing something wrong. 
File parsing is done by running some .exe on the file, which uses <5mb or ram.
Task scheduler runs every time timer thread elapses. But it runs OOM even before timer elapsed for 2nd time.

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(AssemblyDirectory);
        FileInfo[] allSrcFiles = info.GetFiles("*.dat").OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
        var validSrcFiles = allSrcFiles.Where(p => (DateTime.Now - p.CreationTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        var newFilesToParse = validSrcFiles.Where(f => !ProcessedFiles.Contains(f.Name));
        if (newFilesToParse.Any()) Console.WriteLine("Adding " + newFilesToParse.Count() + " files to the Queue");
        foreach (var file in newFilesToParse)
        {
            FilesToParseQueue.Enqueue(file);
            ProcessedFiles.Add(file.Name);
        }
        if (!busy)
        {

            if (FilesToParseQueue.Any())
            {
                busy = true;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("There are " + FilesToParseQueue.Count + " files in queue. Processing...");
            }
            var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(coresCount); //4
            TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
            while (FilesToParseQueue.Any())
            {
                factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    FileInfo file;
                    if (FilesToParseQueue.TryDequeue(out file))
                    {
                        //Dequeue();
                        ParseFile(file);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (!FilesToParseQueue.Any())
            {
                busy = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Finished processing Files in the Queue. Waiting for new files...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to mix some shared mutable state (`busy` + `FilesToParseQueue`) and fire-and-forget asynchronous tasks. You're going to lose. Even with a `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`. Look at TPL Dataflow - it's a near-perfect fit for what you're needing to achieve (or use `Parallel.ForEach` if you're ok with blocking code).

Comment: Thanks. I tried Parallel.Foreach, but it was trying to launch too many tasks, and it was very inefficient - Disk driver was busy for hours and machine was very slow. Processing file is I/O intensive task (very little computation actually) So I was trying to limit number of concurrent threads to number or cores.... I'm trying to find some TPL example that could work for me. In case you have any link to some examples - would be glad to read. Thanks.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, i => ...)` is what you want. I'll put together an example with your specific scenario in mind shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic solution**

You can actually fix your code by stripping it down to the bare essentials like so:

```
// This is technically a misnomer. It should be
// called "FileNamesQueuedForProcessing" or similar.
// Non-thread-safe. Assuming timer callback access only.
private readonly HashSet<string> ProcessedFiles = new HashSet<string>();
private readonly LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler LimitedConcurrencyScheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(Environment.ProcessorCount);

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(AssemblyDirectory);

    // Slightly rewritten to cut down on allocations.
    FileInfo[] newFilesToParse = info
        .GetFiles("*.dat")
        .Where(f =>
            (DateTime.Now - f.CreationTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) && // I'd consider removing this filter.
            !ProcessedFiles.Contains(f.Name))
        .OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime)
        .ToArray();

    if (newFilesToParse.Length != 0) Console.WriteLine("Adding " + newFilesToParse.Count() + " files to the Queue");

    foreach (FileInfo file in newFilesToParse)
    {
        // Fire and forget.
        // You can add the resulting task to a shared thread-safe collection
        // if you want to observe completion/exceptions/cancellations.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => ParseFile(file)
            , CancellationToken.None
            , TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach
            , LimitedConcurrencyScheduler
        );

        ProcessedFiles.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Note how I am not doing any kind of load balancing on my own, instead relying on `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` to perform as advertised - that is, accept all work items immediately on `Task.Factory.StartNew`, queue them internally and process them *at some point in the future* on up to [N = max degree of parallelism] thread pool threads.

P.S. I'm assuming that `OnTimedEvent` will always fire on the same thread. If not, a small change will be necessary to ensure thread safety:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (ProcessedFiles)
    {
        // As above.
    }
}
```

**Alternative solution**

Now, here's a slightly more novel approach: how about we get rid of the timer and `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` and encapsulate *all* of the processing in a single, modular pipeline? There will be a *lot* of blocking code (unless you break out TPL Dataflow - but I'll stick with Base Class Library types here), but the messaging between stages is *so* easy it makes for a really appealing design (in my opinion of course).

```
private async Task PipelineAsync()
{
    const int MAX_FILES_TO_BE_QUEUED = 16;

    using (BlockingCollection<FileInfo> queue = new BlockingCollection<FileInfo>(boundedCapacity: MAX_FILES_TO_BE_QUEUED))
    {
        Task producer = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(AssemblyDirectory);
                    HashSet<string> namesOfFilesQeueuedForProcessing = new HashSet<string>();

                    FileInfo[] newFilesToParse = info
                        .GetFiles("*.dat")
                        .Where(f =>
                            (DateTime.Now - f.CreationTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) &&
                            !ProcessedFiles.Contains(f.Name))
                        .OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime) // Processing order is not guaranteed.
                        .ToArray();

                    foreach (FileInfo file in newFilesToParse)
                    {
                        // This will block if we reach bounded capacity thereby throttling
                        // the producer (meaning we'll never overflow the handover collection).
                        queue.Add(file);
                        namesOfFilesQeueuedForProcessing.Add(file.Name);
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Exception? Cancellation? We'll let the
                // consumer know that it can wind down.
                queue.CompleteAdding();
            }
        });

        Task consumer = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), options, file => ParseFile(file)); 
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

This pattern in its general form is described in Stephen Toub's "Patterns of Parallel Programming", page 55. I highly recommend having a look.

The trade-off here is the amount of blocking that you'll be doing due to using `BlockingCollection<T>` and `Parallel.ForEach`. The benefits of the pipeline as a concept are numerous though: new stages (`Task` instances) are easy to add, completion and cancellation easy to wire in, both producer and consumer exceptions are observed, and all the mutable state is delightfully local.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your basic solution works wonderfully.  The only (tiny) downside - is that I don't actually know how many tasks(files) are finished at a given time out of total amount of  queued for processing.     Second solution indeed looks very elegant. But I still have learning to do to understand it - haven't used async/await before.  I tried using it "as-is" - just copy-pasted, and simply launched the pipeline.   Well, it does process the files that are already in the folder, but does not process the files that are being added after pipeline is launched.

Comment: How do I make the _producer_ add new files?  Here's my scenario: When I launch the pipeline - there are already , say, 1000 files in the folder, and another (unrelated) process writes new files approx 15files/minute. Once I launch the pipeline  - it starts to process the 1000 "old" files, once it finishes (after some 20min) - it stops, and does NOT process new files that were added in the mean time.  Basic solution DOES work as expected though.

Comment: @Mike, there's a bigger downside to the simple solution: and that is you don't know if any of your parsing tasks have errored. That's addressed by the pipeline (which I've also fixed by the way: I had forgotten the `while` loop in the producer; it will now loop indefinitely and pick up the files added after the initial run, as per your requirements). Having said this, I *strongly* encourage you to take a look at Stephen Cleary's answer. He literally wrote a book on the subject.

Comment: P.S. `PipelineAsync` now `async` to ensure proper disposal of the `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code keeps on creating new `Task`s as long as there are files to process and it does so much faster that the files can be processed. But it has no other limit (like the number of files in the directory), which is why it quickly runs out of memory.

A simple fix would be to move the dequeuing outside the loop:

```
while (true)
{
    FileInfo file;
    if (FilesToParseQueue.TryDequeue(out file))
    {
        factory.StartNew(() => ParseFile(file));
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You would get even better performance if you created just one `Task` per core and processed the files using a loop inside those `Task`s.

Comment: I tried what you suggested - it doesn't run out of memory, but it parses only part of the files, and majority of the files are not processed at all. I don't understand how it can open more than 4 tasks in parallel, since it should be limited by coresCount:   var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(coresCount); //4      So it now it tries to dequeue all the files that have to be processed, but creates only 4 tasks, and rest of items in queue are lost ? Is that what is happening here?

Comment: @Mike, it's the *execution* of the tasks that is limited by the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`. Their *enqueuing* is completely unbounded in your case. All these `Task` objects representing your `TryDequeue/ProcessFile` are allocated in a tight loop which relies on an external condition which may or may not be satisfied before you run out of memory.

Comment: @Kirill. Thanks for explaining this. I understand now why it was running out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem (where you *queue* mutliple units of work, and want them processed in *parallel*) is a perfect fit for [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private async void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(AssemblyDirectory);
  FileInfo[] allSrcFiles = info.GetFiles("*.dat").OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
  var validSrcFiles = allSrcFiles.Where(p => (DateTime.Now - p.CreationTime) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
  var newFilesToParse = validSrcFiles.Where(f => !ProcessedFiles.Contains(f.Name));
  if (newFilesToParse.Any()) Console.WriteLine("Adding " + newFilesToParse.Count() + " files to the Queue");

  var blockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
  {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = coresCount,
  };
  var block = new ActionBlock<FileInfo>(ParseFile, blockOptions);

  var filesToParseCount = 0;
  foreach (var file in newFilesToParse)
  {
    block.Post(file);
    ProcessedFiles.Add(file.Name);
    ++filesToParseCount;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("There are " + filesToParseCount + " files in queue. Processing...");

  block.Complete();
  await block.Completion;
  Console.WriteLine("Finished processing Files in the Queue. Waiting for new files...");
}
```

Comment: I wanted to try this solution, but my VS2013 can't recognize `ActionBlock` and  `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`. What am I mising? I have target framework 4.5.1.

Comment: @Mike, you need to install the TPL Dataflow NuGet. Right-click your project and choose "Manage NuGet packages". `ActionBlock<TInput>` lives in the `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` namespace - add the relevant `using` directive at the top of your .cs file.